# How to get any command / task (ex: Ansible - Yum Install ) / stdout output i.e. Pretty print or Beautify / Lint aligned output

Tags: linux, ansible, output, ansible-2.x, lint

Ansible version: 2.8.3 or Any

I'm using `-m <module>` Ansible's **ad-hoc** command to ensure the following package is installed **--OR--** let's say if I have a task to install few yum packages, like (i.e. How can I do the same within a task (possibly when ***I'm not using ansible's shell / command*** modules):

```
  - name: Installing necessary yum dependencies
    yum:
      name:
        - wget
        - python-devel
        - openssl-devel
      state: latest
```

**It works,** but how can I get the output of whole `yum` operation in a nice output format (instead of getting a one line format with bunch of `\n` characters embedded in it); like what we usually get when we run the same command (`yum install <some_package>`) on Linux command prompt.

**I want to ansible to retain a command's output in original format**

The line I want to see in more linted/beautified way is: `Loaded plugins: ...`

```
[root@ansible-server test_ansible]# ansible -i hosts all -m yum -a 'name=ncdu state=present'
host1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 0,
    "results": [


"Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\nLoading mirror speeds from cached hostfile\n * base: mirror.netsite.dk\n * elrepo: mirrors.xservers.ro\n * epel: fedora.mirrors.telekom.ro\n * extras: centos.mirrors.telekom.ro\n * remi-php70: remi.schlundtech.de\n * remi-safe: remi.schlundtech.de\n * updates: centos.mirror.iphh.net\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ncdu.x86_64 0:1.14-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n\nDependencies Resolved\n\n================================================================================\n Package         Arch              Version                Repository       Size\n================================================================================\nInstalling:\n ncdu            x86_64            1.14-1.el7             epel             51 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nInstall  1 Package\n\nTotal download size: 51 k\nInstalled size: 87 k\nDownloading packages:\nRunning transaction check\nRunning transaction test\nTransaction test succeeded\nRunning transaction\n  Installing : ncdu-1.14-1.el7.x86_64                                       1/1 \n  Verifying  : ncdu-1.14-1.el7.x86_64                                       1/1 \n\nInstalled:\n  ncdu.x86_64 0:1.14-1.el7                                                      \n\nComplete!\n"
    ]
}
```

Example of the aligned linted/beautified format that I'm looking for, is shown below if I execute: **# yum install ncdu**, we need need the exact same output, but how it's per line and easy to read/visualize on stdout.

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is registered with an entitlement server, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.


*** WARNING ***
The subscription for following product(s) has expired:
  - Oracle Java (for RHEL Server)
  - Red Hat Ansible Engine
  - Red Hat Beta
  - Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for x86_64
  - Red Hat Container Images
  - Red Hat Container Images Beta
  - Red Hat Developer Tools (for RHEL Server)
  - Red Hat Developer Tools Beta (for RHEL Server)
  - Red Hat Developer Toolset (for RHEL Server)
  - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host
  - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta
  - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
  - Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
  - Red Hat Software Collections (for RHEL Server)
  - Red Hat Software Collections Beta (for RHEL Server)
  - dotNET on RHEL (for RHEL Server)
  - dotNET on RHEL Beta (for RHEL Server)
You no longer have access to the repositories that provide these products.  It is important that you apply an active subscription in order to resume access to security and other critical updates. If you don't have other active subscriptions, you can renew the expired subscription.

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncdu.x86_64 0:1.15.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                    Arch                                                         Version                                                             Repository                                                  Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 ncdu                                                       x86_64                                                       1.15.1-1.el7                                                        epel                                                        52 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 52 k
Installed size: 88 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
ncdu-1.15.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                           |  52 kB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : ncdu-1.15.1-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1/1
  Verifying  : ncdu-1.15.1-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1/1

Installed:
  ncdu.x86_64 0:1.15.1-1.el7

Complete!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ways:

Inside Ansible's (2.5 onwards) configuration file `ansible.cfg` file (either global, in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`, or a ***local one in your playbook/project***), we can add the following lines under the `[defaults]` section:

```
[defaults]
nocows = True

# Use the debug/yaml/json callback plugins as necessary for your output type.
stdout_callback = debug 
#stdout_callback = debug
#stdout_callback = json

# Use the stdout_callback when running ad-hoc commands.
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

At command line, we can pass the following ENV variable:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible or ansible-playbook ...
```

If using a `task` as shown below, and if I registered the variable in a task, then I can just use:

```
  - name: Installing necessary yum dependencies
    yum:
      name:
        - wget
        - python-devel
        - openssl-devel
      register: yum_std_out
      state: latest
```

Then, I can use:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ yum_std_out.split('\n') }}"
```

and if the output of a given Ansible module is other than stdout/debug i.e. in XML or JSON, then in Ansible, configuration file (as listed above), you can enable the appropriate setting by uncommenting i.e.

```
#stdout_callback = debug
#stdout_callback = json
```

More info:

[debug plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/debug_callback.html)

[anstomlog plugin](https://blog.alexgittings.com/improving-the-ansible-output-with-anstomlog/)

[YAML plugin](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/use-ansibles-yaml-callback-plugin-better-cli-experience)

Comment: Doesn't Ansible have a way to just "print" the `\n`, since those are new line characters? Rather than the split I mean. I agree this is the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for any solution, just grepping what you need and using `printf` will do what you want - the string is "beautified", it's just marking the new lines with `\n`:

```
ansible -i hosts all -m yum -a 'name=ncdu state=present' | grep Loaded | xargs printf
```

If you have more than one result line:

```
ansible -i hosts all -m yum -a 'name=ncdu state=present'  | grep Loaded | while read -r line; do printf "$line"; done
```

Of course, this does not check the result was a success, but it's unclear if you want that as well. To print everything (including the result part nicely):

```
ansible -i hosts all -m yum -a 'name=ncdu state=present' | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "$line\n"; done
```

since the everything that does not contain `\n` will print normally. `IFS=` will preserve the indentation.

Comment: That would do it at command line prompt at Linux leve. I forgot to mention that I actually wanted to achieve the same within Ansible's TASK level (updated my question to add task section). How can I do the same within a task (possibly if I'm not using ansible's shell / command modules). I see I  can register the output of ansible task run to a variable and trying to see how can I print that registered variable into nice aligned format (without requiring another task/shell/command output) otherwise it'll echo it twice (unless I mask the stdout off on main task's operation).